# How do I escape to Obristan with my whole family?

Tags: papers-please

On Day 29 I received an Obristan passport that I could get forged so that I can leave for Obristan. At the end of days 29, 30, and 31 I only have the option of escaping by myself, not with my whole family. I have more than enough money to cover the cost of forging passports for my whole family (I have over 300 credits, and I didn't adopt my niece), but I'm never given the option to escape with my family.

I think that I need to get 4 more Obristan passports, but I'm never given the option to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to confiscate Obristan passports from people that come through your booth, the same way that you would confiscate ones for citizens.  This is obviously against the rules and you will be fined every time you do it, but there is no other way to collect the passports you need.

Comment: You don't get fined for your first 2 citations each day, so as long as you don't make any other transgressions all will be well. 


There tend to be quite a lot of Obristanis coming through from day 29 onwards, so you can spread out your efforts over 3 days if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

for everyone to escape you must

- Confiscate Obristran passports
- Have 50-150 credits ready (depending on whether you adopted the niece or killed at least three family members and didn't adopt the niece)
- Not have triggered any other endings.

If everyone is fine on the day you are ready, don't pay the bills. Also, if not all alive family members are taken you will trigger ending 17 where you won't know the safety of any other alive family members not taken.